# Error after upgrading to latest CiviCRM version

Tags: upgrade

After upgrading, I see the following message appear:

```
Strict warning: Declaration of DB_common::raiseError() should be compatible with & PEAR::raiseError($message = NULL, $code = NULL, $mode = NULL, $options = NULL, $userinfo = NULL, $error_class = NULL, $skipmsg = false) in require_once() (line 29 of /s***/crm.***.com/***/***/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php).
```

All operations seem to be working fine though. Please help.

Regards
Atif

Comment: Atif - welcome to SE. It would be helpful if you were to say which version of CiviCRM as the "latsest" version will change. Also what CMS you are using.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Mick. I have upgraded to 5.13.5 from 4.7. I'm using Drupal 7